# Como converter um string em List<int>?

Tags: c#, .net, string, lista

Tenho a seguinte variável e gostaria de converte-la para uma lista de inteiro:

```
string variavel = "1,2,3";
```

Há como convertê-la para uma lista de inteiros?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sim,

```
string variavel = "1,2,3";
var numeros = variavel.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

ou

```
var numeros = variavel.Split(',').Select(item => int.Parse(item)).ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado @MaiconCarraro, deu certo aqui :-)

Answer (score 4):

Também pode ser feito desta maneira:

```
string variavel = "1,2,3";

List<int> inteiros = new List<int>();

foreach (var valor in variavel.Split(','))
   inteiros.Add(int.Parse(valor));
```

Uma outra maneira, mais simples seria desta forma.

```
 List<int> num = Array.ConvertAll(variavel.Split(','), s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado @MeuChapeu, deu certo aqui também dessa maneira, mais eu estou utilizando uma ferramenta  o ReSharper e ele fala pra substituir o `List<int>` por `var`. Tem algum problema?

Comment: @Danilo É mais o estilo de programar mesmo, o motivo do ReSharper fazer isso é porque ele sempre tenta facilitar a refatoração então quando você tiver um método que possa mudar o type do retorno se você tiver utilizando `var` não vai mudar nada, agora se você especificou o type vai precisar refatorar depois.

Answer (score 4):

Se pudesse usar o *array* bastava usar o [`Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#overloads). E se tivesse um método que retornasse lista ao invés de *array*, também simplificaria, mas nem acho que deveria existir:

```
var lista = "1, 2, 3".Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9301290/221800).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = "1, 2, 3".Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(lista.GetType());
        foreach (var item in lista) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OkXil5). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ry26Gv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitList.cs).

Comment: Mais onde estou convertendo para uma lista do tipo inteiro?

Comment: @Danilo é verdade, eu não li o `int` aí não tem jeito mesmo, vou mudar, vai ficar igual a resposta aceita, mas vou dar o crédito de onde tem isto.

Answer (score 0):

E Caso queira usar o "for":

```
  public static List<int> StringToListOfInt(){
      
        string a = "1, 2, 3";
        var x = a.Split(",");
        List<int> nums = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            nums.Add(int.Parse(x[i]));
        }
        return nums;
  }
```